# Ionic 4 Need to update by app on playstore

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am going to publish my ionic app on the play store. But I need to add an auto-update in my app. like when the new version is an available user will update automatically. I learn about ionic deploy but some people say ionic deploy only change the content of the app, not the native code( native code mean to add a new function, page, etc)

If it is true so what is the way to update my app auto? I know the plugin of app update but it will not work on ios.

Answer (score 1):

In our App we used [Code Push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/code-push) by Microsoft. I think it is the same as Ionic Deploy.

With Features like this you can update the content of the App, but because your Content in an Ionic App isn't native, you are able to update functions, add Pages, add Assets, change Function Logic, etc. What you can not do is updating real native Stuff, like increasing Version Number, adding new Cordova Plugin, etc.

**Remember:** Functions, Pages, etc. are not Native in an Ionic App. These are created by Angular (or React, or whatever Framework you use) and compiled in the `www`-Folder, which kind of just runs into the Native WebView. So the whole `www` Folder can be updated without going through the App Store.

All really native Stuff is not possible with this. So you can not increase the Version Number for Example. Also adding a Cordova Plugin is not possible because this produced real native Code.

Just to let you know:
Last Month we in our Team decided to remove this Feature, as it could happen that the Sources to update are very large and most people enabled automatic app store updates over night.

Comment: Yeah I agree that this isn't possible. Just to add one thought, if you cannot let users stay on older versions then you can always add a script that checks the version number and stop them from using the app until they update. Not perfect but could solve your issue if you need to upgrade the native code as well.